# get id of affected row in codeigniter after an update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

How do i get the id of the affected row after doing an update in CodeIgniter?

**NOTE:** `$this->db->insert_id()` which gets the last insert id returns **0** after an doing an update like so `$this->db->update(_table_name)`.

Doing `$this->db->affected_rows()` will return **x** number of affected rows so my question is, is there any way to get the individual **id** of the affected rows after doing a `$this->db->update()`?

Comment: yes run the same conditions with in the select `SELECT [cols] FROM [tbl] WHERE [CONDITION FROM UPDATE]`

Comment: my bad, i had the **id** all along, I just could not think straight.

Comment: is this for me? if yes so i didn't understand this :p

Comment: Before asking question. Must try it first. From all means. @awsmketchup

Answer (score 2):

```
return $this->db->affected_rows();
```

if you check record is updated or not then use below code;
Other wise you need to return manually id